# Manually calling mount point

Tags: networking, mount, fstab, smb, shared-folders

In my /etc/fstab file, i defined a network shared folder mount. Like so:

```
//172.16.30.50/secret2/secret3 /media/secret1/secret2/secret3 cifs credentials=/home/myuser/aux/some_file.txt,x-systemd.automount,vers=1.0 0 0
```

Sometimes it gets clunky and unmounts it at some random point, or the shared folder host closes the connection. In those cases i just use `mount -a` which mounts all defined mount points. But my list of mounts started to grow and i don't wanna mount all of them at the same time. **I want to mount only one of them (the one defined above). And i don't wanna mount it using full path, is it possible to do some labeling or naming ?** How can i do it ?

E.g: `mount my_mount_point_1`

Thank you.

Comment: Have you considered setting it up as an automount?

Comment: @jsbillings isn't it already automount, since i passed "x-systemd.automount" parameter. Also, even if it is automount it can still unmounted if the host closes the connection or gets shutdown.

Comment: If it is being set up as an automount unit, it will automatically disconnect. Just access the mount point to make it automatically reconnect, no need to run `sudo mount ….`

Answer (score 1):

You could very well just add a shell alias for `mount /media/secret1/secret2/secret3`, e.g.

```
alias "secret3mount=mount /media/secret1/secret2/secret3"
```

in, for example, your ~/.bashrc.

`mount` itself has no further shortcuts.

By the way, this sounds a lot like you have dependencies between mounts and other things you want to do on your PC, for example "I need to mount this and that before starting the backup, which I do once a week". In that case: mounts can be handled by systemd unit files, and these can have mutual dependencies, so that starting the backup job automatically mounts things.

Comment: Alias makes sense actually. Will comment after trying it.  For the second part of your answer, yes that is correct. But i'm actually preparing a shell script so I'll use the mount command in the script.

Comment: Since I'm planning to use it inside a bash script, it's not working. I created the alias and added it to ~/.bashrc, it works on normal client terminal but command is not recognized on bash script files.

Comment: yeah, but in a script, you could just use a variable to store the path...